# Recursive function, geometric progression

Tags: c++

I've just started learning C++ and I came across  a simple problem but couldn't solve. Help me please,

In geometric progression, b1=2, r=3.
Create recursive function that outputs initial n sequences of progression. n should be input.

Comment: Some guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `b1` is the initial number and `r` is the multiplier (ratio?), that would give `2, 6, 18, 54, ...`.

The *pseudo-code* for such a beast would be:

```
def geometric (limit, current, multiplier):
    if limit <= 0: return
    print(current)
    geometric(limit - 1, current * multiplier, multiplier)

def main():
    b1 = 2
    r = 3
    n = input("How many terms? ")
    geometric(n, b1, r)
```

The reason it's pseudo-code is that I tend to prefer for educational questions since people learn a lot more by converting it rather than just being given an answer.

So, in terms of how the recursive function works, you pass it the number of terms remaining along with the current term and the multiplier.

Provided it hasn't reached its base case (number of terms remaining is zero), it prints the current term then recursively calls itself, adjusting the arguments so as to approach the base case.

Once it *has* reached the base case, it will return (from *all* recursive levels).

---

Turning that into C++ is an exercise I'll leave for the reader, but I *can* provide something similar so you will see the approach taken.

Let's say you wanted to sum all the numbers between 1 and a given number. It has the same features as any recursive solution, including the one posed in your question:

- an operation that can be defined in terms of a simpler operation; and
- the base case.

In C++, a complete program to do that would be something like:

```
#include <iostream>

void recurse(int number, int sum) {
    // Base case for printing and returning.

    if (number <= 0) {
        std::cout << "Sum is " << sum << '\n';
        return;
    }

    // Recurse to next level.

    recurse(number - 1, sum + number);
}

int main() {
    int myNum;
    std::cout << "Enter your number: ";
    std::cin >> myNum;
    recurse(myNum, 0);
}
```

Some sample runs:

```
Enter your number: 3
Sum is 6

Enter your number: 4
Sum is 10

Enter your number: 5
Sum is 15

Enter your number: 6
Sum is 21

Enter your number: 100
Sum is 5050
```

---

The explanatory text on your *specific* question, along with the C++ code showing how to do it for a different question, should hopefully be enough for you to work it out.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! But could you do it a bit simpler, I couldn't understand 'print current'. Please

Comment: @Panda, `print current` is intended to just print out the current value of the `current` variable for the user to see. See the `std::cout` line in the C++ code for how to do this, basically `std::cout << current << '\n';`

Comment: @paxdiablo I'm beginner, I would be thankful if you send me simple whole code

Comment: it is giving me a lot of errors in Dev C++

Comment: @Panda Re: "_I would be thankful if you send me simple whole code_" - that's absolutely off topic. The help paxdiablo has given you is more than what you should hope for given your original question. Read it, try to understand it, let it sink in - then use it to solve your particular problem.

Comment: @Panda, if you want the code, you'll have to get it elsewhere, I'm afraid. I'm rather passionate about teaching others so I'd rather risk losing the rep :-) Now, if you have *specific* questions about the code you've written and want help, the kosher thing to do is just ask another question, showing the work you've done. I (and a great many others) will be happy to help out.